# How do I do a diff using java-diff-utils for single-line files that may be large in Java?

Tags: java, diff, large-files

I'm using **java-diff-utils**: https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-diff-utils/

And it works great, except when a **large file is all on one single line**.

I use a BufferedReader to read each line in and because of that it I get a **Java Heap Out of Memory Exception**.

What can I do to handle loading large single-line files for use with java-diff-utils?

Here is my code:

```
import difflib.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestDiffUtils {

    public TestDiffUtils() {

    }

    // Helper method to read the files to compare into memory, convert them to a list of Strings which can be used by the DiffUtils library for comparison
    private static List fileToLines(String filename) {
        List lines = new LinkedList();
        String line;
        try {
            URL path = TestDiffUtils.class.getResource(filename);
            File f = new File(path.getFile());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lines;
    }

    // Helper method to convert a String to List<Character> : to be used with DiffUtils.diff() method when finding character diffs within the line diffs
    public static List<Character> asList(final String string) {
        return new AbstractList<Character>() {
            public int size() { return string.length(); }
            public Character get(int index) { return string.charAt(index); }
        };
    }

    private static void performDiff(String testName) {
        String origFileName = null;
        String revisedFileName = null;

        Boolean continueTest = true;    // continue unless we can't

        if( testName.compareTo("large-file-test") == 0 )
        {
            origFileName = "test_large_file.xml";
            revisedFileName = "test_large_file_revised.xml";
        }else if( testName.compareTo("small-file-test") == 0 ){
            origFileName = "originalFile.txt";
            revisedFileName = "revisedFile.txt";
        }else if( testName.compareTo("large-file-test-single-line") == 0 ){
            origFileName = "test_large_file_SingleLine.xml";
            revisedFileName = "test_large_file_revised_SingleLine.xml";
        }else{
            continueTest = false;
        }

        if( continueTest && origFileName != null && revisedFileName != null ) {
            // Convert the orig and revised files to List<String> format that DiffUtils.diff() uses
            List<String> originalLines = fileToLines(origFileName);
            List<String> revisedLines = fileToLines(revisedFileName);

            // Get the line-by-line diffs
            Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalLines, revisedLines);
            List<Delta> deltas = patch.getDeltas();
            for (Delta delta : deltas) {
                // The line in the orig file that this current diff occurs at
                int lineOfDiffInOrig = delta.getOriginal().getPosition() + 1;

                // Only continue with the diff if the revised lines is not empty (we will get IndexOu0tOfBoundsExceptions if we don't do this check)
                if (delta.getOriginal().getLines().size() > 0 && delta.getRevised().getLines().size() > 0) {
                    // Get orig and revised lines in List<Character> format
                    List<Character> origChars = asList(((String) delta.getOriginal().getLines().get(0)));
                    List<Character> revisedChars = asList(((String) delta.getRevised().getLines().get(0)));

                    // Get the character-by-character diffs
                    Patch deltaPatch = DiffUtils.diff(origChars, revisedChars);
                    List<Delta> strDeltas = deltaPatch.getDeltas();
                    for (Delta strDelta : strDeltas) {
                        int charPosOfDiffInOrig = strDelta.getOriginal().getPosition() + 1;
                        int lengthOfDiffInOrig = charPosOfDiffInOrig + strDelta.getOriginal().size();

                        System.out.println("Line" + lineOfDiffInOrig + " : [" + charPosOfDiffInOrig + "," + lengthOfDiffInOrig + "]");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //performDiff("large-file-test");
        //performDiff("small-file-test");
        performDiff("large-file-test-single-line");
    }
}
```

--
**MyersDiff code:**

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package difflib.myers;

import difflib.ChangeDelta;
import difflib.Chunk;
import difflib.DeleteDelta;
import difflib.Delta;
import difflib.DiffAlgorithm;
import difflib.InsertDelta;
import difflib.Patch;
import difflib.myers.DiffNode;
import difflib.myers.DifferentiationFailedException;
import difflib.myers.PathNode;
import difflib.myers.Snake;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.List;

public class MyersDiff implements DiffAlgorithm {
    public MyersDiff() {
    }

    public Patch diff(List<?> original, List<?> revised) {
        return this.diff(original.toArray(), revised.toArray());
    }

    public Patch diff(Object[] orig, Object[] rev) {
        try {
            PathNode path = buildPath(orig, rev);
            return buildRevision(path, orig, rev);
        } catch (DifferentiationFailedException var5) {
            var5.printStackTrace();
            return new Patch();
        }
    }

    public static PathNode buildPath(Object[] orig, Object[] rev) throws DifferentiationFailedException {
        if(orig == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("original sequence is null");
        } else if(rev == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("revised sequence is null");
        } else {
            int N = orig.length;
            int M = rev.length;
            int MAX = N + M + 1;
            int size = 1 + 2 * MAX;
            int middle = size / 2;
            PathNode[] diagonal = new PathNode[size];
            diagonal[middle + 1] = new Snake(0, -1, (PathNode)null);

            for(int d = 0; d < MAX; ++d) {
                for(int k = -d; k <= d; k += 2) {
                    int kmiddle = middle + k;
                    int kplus = kmiddle + 1;
                    int kminus = kmiddle - 1;
                    PathNode prev = null;
                    int i;
                    if(k != -d && (k == d || diagonal[kminus].i >= diagonal[kplus].i)) {
                        i = diagonal[kminus].i + 1;
                        prev = diagonal[kminus];
                    } else {
                        i = diagonal[kplus].i;
                        prev = diagonal[kplus];
                    }

                    diagonal[kminus] = null;
                    int j = i - k;

                    Object node;
                    for(node = new DiffNode(i, j, prev); i < N && j < M && orig[i].equals(rev[j]); ++j) {
                        ++i;
                    }

                    if(i > ((PathNode)node).i) {
                        node = new Snake(i, j, (PathNode)node);
                    }

                    diagonal[kmiddle] = (PathNode)node;
                    if(i >= N && j >= M) {
                        return diagonal[kmiddle];
                    }
                }

                diagonal[middle + d - 1] = null;
            }

            throw new DifferentiationFailedException("could not find a diff path");
        }
    }

    public static Patch buildRevision(PathNode path, Object[] orig, Object[] rev) {
        if(path == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("path is null");
        } else if(orig == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("original sequence is null");
        } else if(rev == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("revised sequence is null");
        } else {
            Patch patch = new Patch();
            if(path.isSnake()) {
                path = path.prev;
            }

            while(path != null && path.prev != null && path.prev.j >= 0) {
                if(path.isSnake()) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("bad diffpath: found snake when looking for diff");
                }

                int i = path.i;
                int j = path.j;
                path = path.prev;
                int ianchor = path.i;
                int janchor = path.j;
                Chunk original = new Chunk(ianchor, copyOfRange(orig, ianchor, i));
                Chunk revised = new Chunk(janchor, copyOfRange(rev, janchor, j));
                Object delta = null;
                if(original.size() == 0 && revised.size() != 0) {
                    delta = new InsertDelta(original, revised);
                } else if(original.size() > 0 && revised.size() == 0) {
                    delta = new DeleteDelta(original, revised);
                } else {
                    delta = new ChangeDelta(original, revised);
                }

                patch.addDelta((Delta)delta);
                if(path.isSnake()) {
                    path = path.prev;
                }
            }

            return patch;
        }
    }

    public static <T> T[] copyOfRange(T[] original, int from, int to) {
        return copyOfRange(original, from, to, original.getClass());
    }

    public static <T, U> T[] copyOfRange(U[] original, int from, int to, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
        int newLength = to - from;
        if(newLength < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
        } else {
            Object[] copy = newType == Object[].class?(Object[])(new Object[newLength]):(Object[])((Object[])Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength));
            System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0, Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
            return copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking around I noticed some others wrote in about BufferedReader::readLine() but they never experienced problems until around 1.3GB.  Although they may have issues when they line is improperly terminated, i.e. without a carriage return `\n` or line feed `\r`

Comment: I've narrowed it a down a bit since I posted this. It's not the reading of the lines that is an issue. BufferedReader handles it well. It's actually the DiffUtils.diff() method that chokes on it. Specifically it chokes on the MyersDiff implementation of the diff() method (see updated post for MyersDiff decompiled code).

Comment: return this.diff(original.toArray(), revised.toArray()); // this is the line that runs out of heap space memory.